# Adding code into compiled template's constructor

Tags: symfony, twig

So I have this Twig extension that allows adding named widgets that would fetch their contents from the database and echo them, or echo fallback content that's inside the tag:

```
{% widget 'my_text' %}
Hello world
{% endwidget %}
```

I've set up a Twig extension to do this. It consists of a node visitor that collects my nodes when there's no cache, and adds their keys into an array that would then be used for doing the database calls:

```
class WidgetNodeVisitor implements \Twig_NodeVisitorInterface
{

    private $aliases = array();

    public function enterNode(Twig_NodeInterface $node, Twig_Environment $env)
    {
        if ($node instanceof WidgetNode) {
            $env->getExtension('widget')->addAlias($node->getNode('alias')->getAttribute('value'));
        }

        return $node;
    }
    /...
```

The token parser is rather basic and mostly similar to `{% trans %}{% endtrans %}` parser, so there's no need to supply its code (and it works well).

The node class itself looks like this:

```
class WidgetNode extends \Twig_Node
{
    public function __construct(\Twig_NodeInterface $alias, \Twig_NodeInterface $body, $lineno = 0, $tag = null)
    {
        parent::__construct(array('alias' => $alias, 'body' => $body), array(), $lineno, $tag);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->attributes['name'];
    }

    public function compile(\Twig_Compiler $compiler)
    {
        $compiler->addDebugInfo($this);

        $alias = $this->nodes['alias']->attributes['value'];
        $fallback = \addslashes($this->nodes['body']->attributes['data']);

        // This method fetches the data from the DB or cache
        $compiler->raw("echo \$this->env->getExtension('widget')->getWidget('$alias', '$fallback');\n");
    }
}
```

My problem is that each compiled `WidgetNode` would then produce a database call in `getWidget()`. If I had a lot of such nodes in my template, the database load would be way too high. So, I thought that I could collect the widget aliases needed for the whole template, and then make my extension fetch all the needed widgets with `alias IN (...)` SQL query, but for doing this I need a way to somehow modify the cached template's `__construct` or `doDisplay` method so that it would have a call to my extension that would fetch all the widgets needed:

```
class __TwigTemplate_6f3bb8f1b5ab540431a1ab3ff48c625b58765e4f0d0d284fe05a9353ea714de8 extends Twig_Template
{
    public function __construct(Twig_Environment $env)
    {
        parent::__construct($env);

        // We've visited the nodes prior to compilation, so the actual string aliases should be known
        $env->getExtension('widget')->prefetch(array('widget1', 'widget2', ...));
    }
```

But how do I make Twig modify the base template template? I've tried swapping any `\Twig_Node_Module` with a wrapper that would render the cached template constructor in a different way, but it doesn't seem like my changes work. I tried doing the swapping in a `NodeVisitor`.

Also I've noted that `'traits'` node could affect Twig's rendering of the template cache, though there's no documentation or anything.

Any suggestions on how I can modify the cached template's header in my extension?

**UPD.** As [suggested](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1518#issuecomment-57286521) by Christophe Coevoet, wrapping `\Twig_Node_Module` is the right way to go:

> However, by wrapping the Twig_Node_Module in your own node in a node
>   visitor, you would be able to add some logic in doDisplay, by
>   overwriting compileDisplayHeader or compileDisplayBody.

Cristophe also suggests [Kris Wallsmith's blog post on Twig node visitors](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15421960092/twig-node-visitors-part-2) as the starting point for such fix.